# Is it possible to have overlapping subtypes in entitiy framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a model called "victim" with properties such as "education, date of death,..." and I want to split it up into subtypes. I managed to do this with a TPH in entity framework, but some of my victim entities can be multiple subtypes at once. Is it possible to achieve that in entity framework? Otherwise I would have to make a lot of mutually exclusive subtypes to capture all combinations, which kind of defeats the purpose of my generalization.

Comment: You might want to consider composition over inheritance.

Comment: What you call `subtype` sounds like a property or categorization, not an inheritance relation. C# itself doesn't allow multiple inheritance so you can't have overlapping derived types to begin with. At least, not without duplicating the "overlapping" data and an ugly design

Comment: @Agent_L Thank you, this put me in the right direction. I was set on inheritance, probably because that is the only information I found about subtyping in the entity framework documentation.